# GroupBy based on multiple column in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, group-by, eloquent

Single column groupby works fine. but I need to groupby with multiple columns.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewyoB.png)

my code is

$technology_subjects = TechnologySubject::all();

dd($technology_subjects->groupBy('technology_id','semester_id'));

anyone can suggest ?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. Also, do you get any errors with your code?

Comment: `$technology_subjects->groupBy(['technology_id','semester_id'])` wrapped in an array.